# Does quarto support self-contained website as html?

Tags: html, rstudio, quarto

Is it possible to save a quarto website as a self-contained html file?

If I add `self-contained: true`  to the yaml file, it does not work for a website project. The website is exported to the folder `_site`, containing the single htmls files and images.

I am using quarto version

```
> quarto_version()
[1] ‘1.2.269’
```